# WD Green (wd20earx) not reading

Tags: hard-drive

My hard drive was plugged into my blu ray player, I was watching a video and when I went to change the video to the next one, everything just froze. I tried turning my blu ray player off and on again and the hard drive didn't want to read at all. So i tried plugging my hard drive into my pc, doesn't work, and it starts slowing my whole pc down. The first night I tried plugging it in, it worked if I moved it around a little. But now it does not read at all.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

This could be a connection issue. Try using a different cable and a different port. Try it also on a different PC. If this device is externally powered, use a different power socket.
The problem could also be a virus, malware, that affected that certain last video file you watched, thus making the drive malfunction and the system it's hooked up to, to freeze. If you are able, see if you can delete that last video file, move all the others on a safe location if you need them, and scan the drive, see if it gives out any errors and if it still lags the system.
Unfortunately, worst case scenario could be a dying hard drive.

CK_WD

Answer (score 0):

It's likely your hard drive is failing.

If you connect it to another computer and the drive isn't visible on the BIOS, the drive is probably dead.

If it *can* be detected by the BIOS, then you should use Western Digital's [Data Lifeguard Diagnostics](http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=810&sid=3&lang=en) to test the drive for problems.  If the drive is under warranty and still detectable by a computer, running diagnostics will be the first step to submitting a warranty claim.